# Don't understand why am getting a "Tuple index out of range" error

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, tuples

I am fairly new to python and am experiencing an error many have had before yet I cannot fix the following code that recommends games based on the genre of customers' purchase history.

```
game_name = ["COD1", "COD2", "COD3", "SKYRIM", "H1Z1", "CSGO", "BF1", "BF3", "BF4", "GTAV", "GTAIV", "FIFA17", "NBA2K17", "MADDEN17", "PES2017", "NHL17", "MLB17", "PGA17", "F12017", "NBA2017"]
history = [["COD1", "COD2", "SKYRIM", "H1Z1", "NHL17", "MLB17", "CSGO", "BF1", "BF3", "F12017"], ["FIFA17", "NBA2K17", "MADDEN17", "PES2017", "COD3", "SKYRIM", "MLB17", "PGA17", "NBA2017", "GTAIV"], ["COD2", "COD3", "PES2017", "NHL17", "BF4", "GTAV", "GTAIV", "MLB17", "PGA17", "F12017"]]
forename = ["Joe", "George", "Oliver"]
HistoryGenre=[["Action", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Sport"], ["Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Action"], ["Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport"]]
rr=1
ActionCounter=0
SportCounter=0
while rr==1:
    rec=input("Who would you like to recommend games for?")
    if rec in forename:
        rr+=1
        r=forename.index(rec)
        ActionCounter = HistoryGenre[r][:10].count("Action")
        SportCounter = HistoryGenre[r][:10].count("Sport")
        if SportCounter==ActionCounter:
            both_list=game_name
            both_remover=0
            for i in both_list:
                if both_list[both_remover] in history[r]:
                    both_list.remove(both_list[both_remover])
                else:
                    both_remover+=1
                    loops=1
            for x in range(1):
                rec1=random.randint(0,len(both_list)-1)
                while loops==1:
                    for x in range(1):
                        rec2=random.randint(0,len(both_list)-1)
                        if rec2!=rec1:
                            loops+=1
                        else:
                            loops=1
                    loops1=1
                    while loops1==1:
                        for x in range(1):
                            rec3=random.randint(0,len(both_list)-1)
                            if rec3!=rec2 and rec3!=rec1:
                                loops1+=1
                            else:
                                loops1=1

                     print("\n")
                     print("{} likes both genres! I recommend {} and {} and {} and {}".format(rec, both_list[rec1], both_list[rec2], both_list[rec3]))
```

The error message occurs on the last line of code and reads `Tuple index out of range`, even though `both_list` is not a `tuple`? Others seem to have had issues due to the fact that I'm formatting an index within this array but nothing I have tried seems to work and the same error message appears, and I don't know which exactly is the source of my error.

Comment: note that you have 5 `{}`s in your string at the end, but only four input items

Comment: I am stupid. Copy and paste error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have less arguments in the `format()` call than you have `{}`'s.